# Navigate only one View by gesture on Gallery

Tags: android, navigation, android-gallery

I have a Gallery that each current item matchs the display dimensions. I want when the user try to "throw" the views to any side, instead of the automatic scrolling, I want to go just to the next View.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'd dump the `Gallery` and use an `ImageView` and a `GestureDetector`. On a swipe, update the `ImageView`.

Comment: I had this approach before when drawing only images inside my custom view. But I had to use a View that supports add any type of content inside (like a WebView for HTML 5 support)

Comment: OK, then use a `ViewFlipper` and a `GestureDetector`. In fact, I have a `ViewSwiper` that does just that: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-viewswiper

Comment: There's a second problem, the View displaying need some gestures also, when there's nothing more to drag, then the View should start scrolling and the new one comes to it's place. Your component supports that?

Comment: Probably not, but I am not certain that `Gallery` will either. Putting gesture-enabled things in gesture-enabled things can be problematic, as evidenced by the long-standing "don't put scrollable things in other scrollable things" restriction.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @CommonsWare let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2741/discussion-between-marcos-vasconcelos-and-commonsware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet. It uses no scrolling constants, instead it relies on scolling key event to handle for different resolutions.

```
private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2){
    return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
    int kEvent;
    if(isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)){ //Check if scrolling left
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
    }
    else{ //Otherwise scrolling right
        kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
    }
    onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
    return true;  
}
```

This piece of code belongs to a galleryView model which extends Gallery and its layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp">
    <com.example.android.GalleryView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:fadingEdge="none"/>
</LinearLayout>
```